# Is the number of Lebesgue covering dimensions a topological property?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Is it correct to characterize the number of dimensions that a topological space has as a 'topological property'? By 'dimensions,' I have in mind Lebesgue covering dimensions.

If the answer is yes, then why? If the answer is no, then what kind of a property is the number of dimensions?

Comment: You need to be very careful with what 'dimension' means.

Comment: What do you mean by the number of dimensions of a space? If you allow general topological spaces, then there are a huge number of possible definitions. Any reasonable definition will, to be sure, be a topological invariant.

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension"? For dimension of a pure vector space, the answer is no, because topology is not part of the structure, although there is a sensible notion of dimension. For a topological space, there are various notions of dimension which are topological invariants, but each of which only really makes sense in the right context.

Comment: Apologies for being vague! What I have in mind are topological spaces. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The vagueness lies not just in the notion of topological spaces, but also in the notion of dimension. Do you mean the [Lebesgue covering dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension)? Or the [small inductive dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension)? Or the [big inductive dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension)? Certainly you don't mean the [dimension in the sense of vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)).

Comment: Apologies once again. I further qualified the question to Lebesgue covering dimensions.

Comment: The Lebesgue covering dimension is a topological property: it is invariant under homeomorphisms. This is clear from its definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn’t it obvious from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) that the covering dimension is a topological invariant? it’s defined purely in terms of open sets and set-theory concepts.

Answer (score -1):

There are many different definitions of dimension in different contexts. Some are topological, most are not.  Look up: topological dimension.